# Can't insert text into my SQLite database

Tags: android

I'm trying to insert text into my SQLite database, but for some reason it doesn't work. It never executes..

Code below (this is my function that I'm calling):

```
public void setInfo(final String tableName, final int id, final String title, final String time, final String content) {

    final String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "("+DB_COLUMN_ID+", "+DB_COLUMN_TITLE+", "+DB_COLUMN_TIME+","+DB_COLUMN_CONTENT+")" + 
    " VALUES ('"+id+"', '"+title+"', '"+time+"','"+content+"";
    final SQLiteStatement stmt = mDatabase.compileStatement(sql); 
    stmt.execute();

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would run through the debugger and check to make sure that you have a database to write to. Also check the Cat Log and look for errors.

Comment: @Shadow: Done all of that stuff, I've also checked that my database openings.

Comment: You say it doesn't execute... Have you tried executeInsert() and getting a Long value returned to see if anything is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the final single quote and the closing parenthesis on the sql statement.  Also the id is type int so it doesn't need any quotes at all.  I'm guessing it should read:

```
final String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + "("+DB_COLUMN_ID+", "+DB_COLUMN_TITLE+", "+DB_COLUMN_TIME+","+DB_COLUMN_CONTENT+")" + 
    " VALUES ("+id+", '"+title+"', '"+time+"','"+content+"')";
```

Comment: Damn it, that big problem, that small solution! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, happens to everyone!